# Class not found exception in a route of slim framework

Tags: php, routes, namespaces, eloquent, slim

I'm starting with Slim+eloquent+twig  (using this presentation http://slides.com/revul/slimframework )  and getting this error:

```
 Type: Error 
 Message: Class 'Localizacao' not found 
 File: /Users/Bigua/Sites/salas/src/routes.php 
 Line: 19
```

I'm trying to list all from a table and pass it to my view. The command "composer update" don't returned any problem.

here my code:

**Composer.json:**

```
{
"name": "slim/slim-skeleton",
"description": "A Slim Framework skeleton application for rapid development",
"keywords": ["microframework", "rest", "router", "psr7"],
"homepage": "http://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton",
"license": "MIT",
"authors": [{
    "name": "Josh Lockhart",
    "email": "info@joshlockhart.com",
    "homepage": "http://www.joshlockhart.com/"
}],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.0",
    "slim/slim": "^3.1",
    "monolog/monolog": "^1.17",
    "illuminate/database": "~5.1",
    "slim/twig-view": "^2.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App/Models\\": "app/models"
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
$app->get('/sala/add', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $this->logger->info("Slim-Skeleton '/salas/add' route");
    // Render index view
    $args['locais'] = Localizacao::all();
    $this->logger->info("locais" . $args);
    return $this->renderer->render($response, 'add_sala.html.twig', $args);
})->setName('sala_add');
```

**Model**

```
<?php
  namespace App\Models;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

  class Localizacao extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'localizacao';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_local';
    public $timestamps    = false;
  }
```

I had read many similar topics here and seems to me that is a problem with namespaces, but I just don't get it where its wrong. Sorry if this is a noob question.

[SOLVED]

The solution its following the two answers, from @marcin-nabiałek and @geggleto  :

Fixed the psr-4:

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\Models\\": "app/models"
}
```

And using namespace correctly:

```
  \App\Models\Localizacao::all()
```

Tnx a lot !!!

Comment: Thx by the tags added @marcin =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your composer entry for PSR-4 autoloading is incorrect

```
"psr-4": {
    "App/Models\\": "app/models"
}
```

Should be

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\Models\\": "app/models"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Localizacao` is in `App\Models` namespace and in `routes.php` you use:

```
Localizacao::all()
```

without any namespace so it's assumed it's from global namespace.

You can replace it into:

```
\App\Models\Localizacao::all()
```

or use it like before but at the top of file add:

```
use App\Models\Localizacao;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let Make things Clear here, the reason why this error is because the name you use for your psr-4 is not the same with the name you declare in your controller class: for example:

```
 "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "{name you will like to use for your name space here, that will represent your application name e.g any name here (App) for instance}\\": "the directory you will like to load your asset,library, routes,middle-ware etc e.g like app or src/"
        }
    }
```